# Images with bottom border in Table

Tags: html, wordpress, image

I am working with a Wordpress theme for a church I volunteer for and building it in a sub-folder (http://www.highlandcc.org/new). There are tons of things that are still rough about this site, but for now ...

I have two questions:

1. The icons to the right of the featured image each are padded with space at the bottom, but I can't seem to find how to remove it. I have tried `cellpadding="0"` `cellspacing="0"` and `border-collapse: collapse` ... all to no avail.
2. This is a builder theme and each section is a module. I am getting extra padding/margin around all of the module. The section 'New to Highland' should sit flush with the image feature section.

Can you help?

Answer (score 1):

Add a CSS class to your "a img" in your widget and write:

```
.yourclass{
  margin: -7px 0 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a space between the images because they are inline-block by default.

In the CSS there is a rule that says:

```
.widget *:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
.widget *:first-child {
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

For your margins to work, make your images `display: block;`

```
.textwidget img {
   display: block;
}
```